# What do we mean with pages/blocks for files in the application level?

Tags: java, database, file, data-structures, random-access

When I read about files in textbooks it seems that some concepts I knew about OS are repeated for files on the application level.
For example the terms **block** and **page** are used for logical representation of data *in files* (so we are not in the HD level organization). But   I can not understand what is the idea here. Do we in the application define a block size and a page size and use that when accessing files e.g. using NIO or blocking IO?
How would we define these sizes normally? Arbitrarily? Am I confused here?

**UPDATE after request of @RobinGreen**
An example of what I am saying is e.g. the slotted-block page structure or the list representation for variable length records described e.g. in the book of Silberschatz for Database System concepts in the section for files

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the operating system **block size** is unrelated to the hard drive's reported sector size in bytes (which is also fake these days - for BIOS compatibility reasons!).

At the application level, you can store data in fixed-size or variable-size blocks, which are unrelated to OS level blocks.

So there are many levels, all unrelated to each other!

Of course it is a good idea to read and write data in chunks, nevertheless. Reading and writing data 1 byte at a time would involve too many round-trips to the kernel, for example. But the right size to use is an empirical question: which size is most efficient for your use case?

**Page sizes** are slightly different. They are defined by the CPU architecture (at least on the x86/x86_64 family) and affect paging/swapping. An application does not directly encounter paging and swapping, but it encounters the effects, in terms of lower performance.

Comment: I am not sure this is what I am asking. The same way that in the application level we can have records of fixed/variable lengths (which is usual) it seems that we can also manipulate a file in pages. I.e. we can do a `seek` on the record and write our object of 20 bytes. But I am not sure how the *page* or *block* fits-in in the code example I gave you

Comment: That is a different meaning of the word "page" than the operating system term I was using. I suggest that it is best to reserve the word page for that meaning. As for writing an object of 20 bytes, I did discuss that: "Of course it is a good idea to read and write data in chunks, nevertheless."

Comment: But this is what the OP is about. Since these terms are used in textbooks for files in application level as well

Comment: Perhaps you could quote a short excerpt from the textbook to show an example of what it is saying, for clarity. Or, even better, some textbooks are online on Google Books - if I knew the textbook and the page number I might be able to read it myself.