# How do we know if a record has already been read?How do we follow record pointers?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, nio

I am confused about algorithms related to processing files.
According to my research online the standard way to represent a variable length record is to put metadata along the data e.g. the length of the record. Additionally if we want to keep the records in some order we can also store a pointer to the next record as part of the fields of the record.
Let's take as an example a file where we have records of the form `<length,data,next_record_ptr>` which is consistent with what I described above.
The code snippets I saw usually read portions of a file in an in-memory buffer which makes sense I guess. Example:

```
ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);  
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(file, READ, WRITE);  
int nread;  
do {  
   nread = fc.read(copy);  
} while (nread != -1 && copy.hasRemaining());
```

I think this is more or less a way to read portions of a file in memory. `SIZE` could be a size to contain multiple of our records.

**Question:** When we have an X number of records in memory, how do we know that a specific record we want to read is in our buffer or not? Example: If I have the pointer to the next record how do I know that this specific record has been loaded as part of the buffer or I must read in more data from file?
This part is mentioned in text books as something simple but I am confused about how this is actually implemented.

To be clear: Giving a sample code in Java would be really great!!!But a clear explanation of this dark point for me with a pseudo-code or a clear algorithm is also great!

**UPDATE:**
To be more clear:
If I have read N records in an array[N]. If I read record `array[0]` and then get `array[0].pointerToNext` which is e.g. `0x123A` in the file. How do I know:
1) If record in location `0x123A` is already read in the buffer i.e. `array[n]`
2) What is the index of this record in the buffer?

Comment: You need to interpret the data somehow as you are reading the file. Read the length and/or pointer and keep track of how many bytes are read and/or the reader's location to find the start point. Also you can store some kind of identifier as part of the data.

Comment: @Radiodef:You mean somehow associate the buffer size with the record pointers?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. Either that or make it large enough that the whole record fits in a buffer where there is overlap. Or read the record in parts. But the bottom line is to keep track of it all somehow. AFAIK all InputStream derivatives have a read with a length argument so you don't necessarily need to read with overlap if you have stored the length in the file.

Comment: @Radiodef:I lost you a bit.If my record in the buffer at index 0 has as value of the pointer of the next record `0x1234` how can I know that the record in that file location was read in the buffer or not?

Comment: Subtract it from the stream's location in the file to see how far ahead or behind it is. If the records do not appear sequentially in the file the best way to do it IMO would be to seek somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792747/seeking-a-bytearrayinputstream-using-java-io?rq=1 Java unfortunately does not typically have an efficient seeking method.

Comment: @Radiodef:Why?What is wrong with `seek` from nio?

Comment: Most of the time the IO classes delegate to native methods so I can't really give you an answer. Through testing you can find out what is the fastest though. Here's a forum thread elsewhere that has another seeking discussion: http://www.coderanch.com/t/278831//java/Seek-BufferedInputStream (potential future visitors note link could be broken).

Answer (score 1):

In files, record pointers are usually stored as record indices or file positions. So you can infer whether you have read a particular record already based on your current position in the file.

In your example you could keep track of the file position using a variable pos:

```
int pos = 0;
int nread;  
do {  
   nread = fc.read(copy);
   if(nread == -1) {
      break;
   } else {
      pos += nread;
   }
} while (copy.hasRemaining());
```

Comment: In your code `pos` after the `while` loop is located in the part of the file *after* the portion we read. How does this position in `pos` help figuring out the position of particular records already read?

Comment: Also how does the index in the buffer found using `pos`?

Comment: Well your question is: "If record in location 0x123A is already read in the buffer". The check for this would be pos > 0x123A. Depending on how you (re)use the buffer, you might just use the buffer position instead of explicitly keeping track of the file position.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the data as you go and factor that in with your reads. This is one way to go about this and probably how I would do it.

```
// read a made up database
// untested

public class SimpleDatabaseRead {

    public void main(String[] args) {
        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("no file");
            return;
        }

        try {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            FileInputStream in = null;

            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(file);

                // rec length will be 16-bit unsigned
                // large array OK, only 64KiB in mem
                byte[] bytes = new byte[65536];

                int bread = 0;
                long fpos = 0, next = 0;

                char[][] rec;

                while ((bread = in.read(bytes, 0, 4)) != -1) {
                    fpos += bread;

                    // length of this rec in bytes
                    int len = ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF);

                    // num entries in rec, for convenience
                    int entries = ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);

                    if (in.read(bytes, 0, len) != len)
                        break;
                    fpos += len;

                    rec = new char[entries][];

                    for (int i = 0, k = 0, h; i < entries; i++) {
                        rec[i] = new char[
                            ((bytes[k++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[k++] & 0xFF)];

                        for (h = 0; h < rec[i].length && k < len; h++)
                            rec[i][h] = ((bytes[k++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[k++] & 0xFF);
                    }

                    for (char[] rec : recs)
                        System.out.println("record: " + new String(rec));

                    if (in.read(bytes, 0, 4) != len)
                        break;
                    fpos += bread;

                    // 48-bit file marker of next rec
                    next = ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 32)
                         | ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 24)
                         | ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 24)
                         |  (bytes[3] & 0xFF);

                    if (next < fpos) {
                        in.close();
                        in = new FileInputStream(file);
                        in.skip(fpos = next);
                    }
                }

            } finally {
                if (in != null) in.close();
            }
            System.out.println("read ended");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (FileNotFoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

There is not really a good way to seek that I know of in Java. [Seeking a ByteArrayInputStream using java.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792747/seeking-a-bytearrayinputstream-using-java-io?rq=1) has some ideas but the gist of it is that basically you either:

- Create a new InputStream as shown in the example or
- Use RandomAccessFile which is reportedly generally slower (test it yourself).

In other words you are better off with data that can be read sequentially.

Instead of reading chunk by chunk another way like you are suggesting would I guess to set the buffer size to an arbitrary length and formulate the record as you go. To tell if the next point is "in the buffer" you would read the pointer and basically use the condition `pointer < fpos + buffer.length`. I don't think I would recommend this approach because the buffer could be less than the length of a record. In this case you would end up formulating the recording in new arrays so you might as well read the whole thing. That's unless they are really, really big and you *must* read the chunks in partially.

Comment: +1:I think I see what you mean, but I am not sure what you are doing with the bit setting.Especially since the parenthesis are wrong e.g. `int len = ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF);`

Comment: They are right. The `& 0xFF` is a mask for the byte values. It's necessary before shifting because otherwise the bytes get automatically promoted to ints by sign extension. You will get very spurious results if you don't mask before shifting. Here's a link that shows the same thing: http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/javas-signed-byte-type-is-a-mistake The first diagram on this page shows how a byte gets sign extended to an int: http://sagarsiddhpura.blogspot.com/2010/08/sign-extension-in-java.html though that page is about right shifts.

Comment: But why are you doing this? What is the number of `entries`?

Comment: Number of entries is for convenience of instantiating the array of values. Storing the number of elements and String lengths lets you store an array of Strings of all different lengths pretty conveniently.

Comment: This is a very useful answer.Actually your answer now started to make me think if it is standard practice to define pages and blocks in our application similar to the OS does. See my other (related) confusion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017744/what-do-we-mean-with-pages-blocks-for-files-in-the-application-level